# Android. Скриншоты + AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, screenshots, su

Люди добрые, помогите, мне нужно делать скриншоты и сохранять их в фоновом режиме.
Писал код, и всё шло хорошо, но возникла проблема.

Вот так работает как надо, но постоянно выскакивает сообщение в Toast о том что выданы права суперпользователя (права выдаются в цикле):

```
class RecordTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
          try {
                  i = 0;
                  while (i < 5) {
                      try {      
                          try {
                              sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                          } catch (IOException e) {
                              e.printStackTrace();
                          }

                          os = sh.getOutputStream();
                          os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/ABScreenRecorder/" + "screenshot" + i + ".png").getBytes("ASCII"));
                          os.flush();
                          os.close();
                          sh.waitFor();
                          TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                      i++;
                  }
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      return null;
    }
}
```

А вот так сохраняет только первый скриншот (вынес выдачу прав за цикл):

```
class RecordTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
          try {
                  try {
                      sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }

                  i = 0;
                  while (i < 5) {
                      try {      
                          os = sh.getOutputStream();
                          os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/ABScreenRecorder/" + "screenshot" + i + ".png").getBytes("ASCII"));
                          os.flush();
                          os.close();
                          sh.waitFor();
                          Thread.sleep(1000);
                          TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                      i++;
                  }
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      return null;
    }
}
```

Как мне исправить второй вариант чтобы всё работало как надо?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте `sh.getOutputStream();` тоже вынести, а `os.close();` делать 1 раз после цикла в finally.
Смысл в том, чтобы держать root shell постоянно открытым.

Возможно, это будет проще сделать с использованием [RootShell](https://github.com/Stericson/RootShell).

Можно ещё попробовать написать весь цикл на шелле:

```
for i in `seq 0 4`; do блабла screencap блабла $i.png; sleep 1; done
```

Comment: Воспользовался RootShell, помогло, спасибо!